# Zoom image in paperclip - Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have one image to upload to my rails app using paperclip, but if you see the image http://46.101.128.163/xetool/custom-assets/orders/53/53/side_1/preview/side_1_53_53_preview.png

I would like to apply a zoom to the image (something like 120%), keeping the width and height (it doesnt matter if the quality of the image gets reduced)

The idea of applying a zoom is to reduce the white space of the image. Is there something i can do to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have any style setup at the moment ? And do the images submitted have a specific format ?

Comment: The image i'm trying to submit is a simple png file like the link above.

Comment: and this is the format i'm using

has_attached_file :attachment,
      styles: { original: '500x500#' },
      default_style: :product,
      path:   ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      url:    "/system/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      convert_options: { all: '-strip -auto-orient -colorspace sRGB' }

    validates_attachment :attachment,
      presence: true,
      content_type: { content_type: accepted_image_types }

Comment: `#` actually center an image and crops what is outside. Lets say you submit an image which is 700x500 it will be automatically cropped to 500x500. (well this is what should happen as per : https://makandracards.com/makandra/1023-paperclip-image-resize-options ) You want to crop some more pixels on both sides of image ?

Comment: But the idea is not to reduce the px of the image, The idea is to submit a 500x500px image, and keep that size and apply an small zoom to the image

Comment: then why don't you define : `{ original: '540x540#' }` and crop 20 pixels on both sides? as per here : http://www.seqmedia.com/2013/05/25/resizing-to-fill-and-cropping-images-with-paperclip-convert_options/ You could do something like: `convert_options: {
      original: " -gravity center -crop '500x500+20+20'"}`

Comment: Amazing answer, i will give it a shot and come back to share the results :)